# Java regexp list of another regexp

Tags: java, regex

I have this regular exp `\d{2}/\d{2}/\d{4}` that we use to validate a string format (weird business rule)

now that field allows a comma separated list, of those strings, so I need to change the reg exp, I know how to do a it for digits, or for strings, but I cant do it for this.

can someone help me? thanks !

Comment: can you please provide an example? what the input output should look like?

Comment: Is that a date field?

Comment: Try `^\d{2}/\d{2}/\d{4}(?:,\d{2}/\d{2}/\d{4})*$`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may use

```
^\d{2}/\d{2}/\d{4}(?:,\d{2}/\d{2}/\d{4})*$
```

It matches your pattern first and then zero or more sequencesof a comma  and your pattern. Anchors are not necessary if you use the pattern with `matches`  method.

Replace the comma with `\s*,\s*` if there can be whitespaces around  the comma.